# Plot x and y ErrorBars from file

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

If I have a set of data like this one saved in a txt file

```
0.0000000328806432649482    68   0.00000000328806432649482   1
0.0000000394567719179379    81   0.00000000328806432649482   1
0.0000000460329005709275    96   0.00000000328806432649482   1
0.0000000526090292239172    110  0.00000000328806432649482   1
0.0000000591851578769068    119  0.00000000328806432649482   1
0.0000000657612865298965    131  0.00000000328806432649482   1
.
.
.
```

The first two coliumns are the measurement values, the last two the errors. How can I plot it with the x and y error bars, without typing the ErrorBar[...] arround every of the last two coloumns by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

values=ImportString[
 "0.0000000328806432649482    68   0.00000000328806432649482   1
  0.0000000394567719179379    81   0.00000000328806432649482   1
  0.0000000460329005709275    96   0.00000000328806432649482   1
  0.0000000526090292239172    110  0.00000000328806432649482   1
  0.0000000591851578769068    119  0.00000000328806432649482   1
  0.0000000657612865298965    131  0.00000000328806432649482   1"
 ];

ErrorListPlot[{{#1, #2}, ErrorBarPlots`ErrorBar @@ {#3, #4}} & @@@ values,
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.15], Automatic}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I used ImportString because it was more expedient to copy/paste your data, but of course you can import the data directly from your file just as easily:

```
values = Import[pathtofile]
```

Comment: Hm, when I copy/paste your code i get this exception:
Function::slotn: Slot number 4 in {{#1,#2},ErrorBar@@{#3,#4}}& cannot be filled from ({{#1,#2},ErrorBar@@{#3,#4}}&)[0.335,0.0000555379,3.4161*10^-6]. >>

Comment: The argument shown in the error `[0.335,0.0000555379,3.4161*10^-6]` that the function was given a list of *three* values, rather than four, so it is missing the error for the y value. Are you working on data in the same format that you showed in the question?

Comment: Yes, I copy/pasted your code, with the ImportString

Comment: @LucaThiede That's weird, I tried to do the same here and it seems to work. I have just edited the answer to remove a new line character, maybe that was messing up the import. If you look at the result of `ImportString` on your end, is it a 6x4 list of lists?

Comment: @LucaThiede maybe you could try importing data directly from your file as well, to see if maybe copy/pasting is messing up the data somehow

Comment: I dont know why, but after restarting Mathematica everything works, thank you

Comment: @LucaThiede eh, it happens that definitions get polluted after some time of use. When I run into this kind of inexplicable random errors, I typically just evaluate `Quit[]` to quit the kernel. This cleans all definitions etc. It's a pretty clean slate. A new kernel will be started automatically the next time you try to evaluate something. Anyway, glad I could help, and thank you for the accept!